# Why is the success of fixed point iteration determined by the the derivative of the function evaluated at the point of intersection?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

I can't seem to understand why cobwebs converge when the derivative of the function evaluated at the point of intersection is between 0 and -1, but cobwebs diverge is the derivative of the function is less than -1.

An intuitive explanation or proof would be appreciated.

Comment: What's a cobweb?

Comment: [*Cobweb Diagrams*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cobweb+diagram&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiFtee8lKDTAhVhz1QKHcqjCVMQsAQIIA&biw=1582&bih=743)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the distance to the fixed point is multiplied by the derivative of the function at each step.  Let the limit be $L$, so $L=f(L)$. If you write $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ and define $e_i=x_i-L$ we have $e_{i+1}=f(x_i)-L=f(L+e_i)-L\approx f(L)+e_if'(L)-L=e_if'(L)$  As long as $|f'(L)| \lt 1$ this will get each estimate closer to the limit.  This shows you want the derivative between $-1$ and $1$.